# How can I find the command that does what button X in palette Y does?

Tags: dm-script

To be specific, I need my code to insert and retract the BF detector in the microscope, as done by the button in the palette "STEM Detector Control". This does not exist as a menu command so `ChooseMenuItem()` is of no help. It seems not to be a separate plugin, so it does not have specific documentation.

But in general, when I know what I want to do and that the functionality is there, how do I find out the command name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't.**

The scripting language does generally not provide commands which do what the UI does. Notable exceptions are the "STEM SI" and "DigiScan" realted script commands, which do provide such functionality.